# If neutrinos were their own antiparticles, would be observe a photon background from $\nu$-$\nu$ annihilations?

Tags: astronomy, antimatter, neutrinos

If neutrinos were their own antiparticles, would we observe a photon background from neutrino-neutrino annihilations?

As neutrinos are so abundant, why don't we observe such a background? Is the cross-section just too small? Or is some conservation law preventing such annihilations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SM model neutrinos cannot annihilate into the photons, because neutrinos have non-zero lepton number. To remedy this, you need to introduce additional lepton-number breaking interaction to the SM. A way to do it is to introduce a mass term for neutrinos. Introducing it directly poses a theoretical problem (to not break the SU(2) electroweak symmetry it would require a non-renormalizable interaction with the Higgs field), so it's usually done indirectly, via neutrino mixing with heavy right-handed neutrinos. Then the mass term for SM neutrinos appears in an effective theory.

In such a model the annihilation is possible, but the cross section would still be extremely low. Neutrinos do not directly interact with photons, which means that to create a photon pair they could only do it via intermediate virtual particles. For example, the process could be represented by the following Feynman diagram (among others, but they are all similar):

[image]

The amplitude for this process would be very low, mostly because of the neutrino mass term, but also because of the fact that it requires a virtual W boson. As a consequence, the process would be undetectable with our current capabilities.

Comment: I means that they annihilate into **ph**otons, not **pr**otons.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts Ah yes, a spelling error on my part. All the argument I've made is about annihilation into photons.

Comment: Does this mean there should be a detectable photon background if neutrinos were *not* their own particles?

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts If the neutrinos were not their own antiparticles, they couldn't annihilate at all. It's just that even if they were, they still wouldn't anihinilate often enough. No detectable background either way.

Comment: Yes, of course.  But there are both neutrinos and anti-neutrinos around?

Comment: @emacs Yes, there are, and they can annihilate. It still requires the mediation of virtual paricles.